# How PHP can interpret this as true?

Tags: php

I try to execute this code

```
<?php
  $id = 'p1';
  echo $id."<br>";
  echo ($id == 0) ? 'true' : 'false';
?>
```

Can anyone explain to me why PHP considers 'p1' equals 0?

Comment: Use `===` or compare to a similar type.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear about this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Php does [implicit conversion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) from string `'p1'` to number `int(0)` when comparing string with number:

```
var_dump((int)'p1');
// int(0)
```

So what's really happening is:

```
echo ((int)'p1') == 0) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

So any string not beginning with a number compared with zero will result into `true`, therefore you get `'true'` in your script.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered
>   FALSE:
>
> ```
> the boolean FALSE itself
> the integer 0 (zero)
> the float 0.0 (zero)
> the empty string, and the string "0"
> an array with zero elements
> an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
> ```
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

Your string isn't empty, thus it is TRUE

Comment: That would apply if the test was `if ($p1)...`. The OP specifically compared the string to a numeric 0, so a conversion to integer was done first.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If we try to compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically

As you can see in the Comparison Operators table on the same page:

> **`$a === $b` -- Identical** -- `TRUE` if `$a` is equal to `$b`, and they are of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that php is loosely typed language.

Basically comparison between different types ( string and an integer in your case ) sometimes has surprising results. And it's basically never advised to compare variables of different type. Nevertheless you can use the [Type Comparison Tables] (click) [1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to check what results to expect and to find which cases won't have surprising outcomes.